# Entity Framework n-to-n query, get last records from navigation table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am using entityframework in my project.

I have 3 tables which are navigated with many to many relationship.
This is my diagram.

[image]

I want to select all my counters id which have last approve status == 15.

I wrote query like this;

```
var sayacOnayDurumlari =
                db.CounterApproveStatus
                    .Where(x => x.ApproveStatusId == 15).OrderByDescending(x=>x.Id)
                    .GroupBy(x => x.CountersId)
                    .Select(e => e.FirstOrDefault());
```

but it takes my older records which are ID == 15

Answer (score 1):

```
 var son =
            db.Counters.Where(
                x => x.CounterApproveStatus.OrderByDescending(t => t.Id).FirstOrDefault().ApproveStatusId == 15)
                .ToList();
```

I tried this and I supposed I achieved it. Is it a good query?

Answer (score 0):

You need group first, then find if the latest Id in that group has desired statusId.
Following syntax may not be exactly right, but you could get idea.

```
var sayacOnayDurumlari =
                db.CounterApproveStatus
                .GroupBy(x => x.CountersId)
                .Select(g => new {
                    CountersId = g.Key, 
                    LatestRecord = g.OrderByDescending(x=> x.Id)
                                  .FirstOrDefault()
                   })
                .Where(g=> g.LatestRecord.ApproveStatusId == 15)                  
                .Select(g => g.CountersId).ToList();
```